# exclude certain buttons

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I've got jquery code like so:

```
$('input:not(:button,:submit),textarea,select').change(function () {
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        if (warnMessage != null) return warnMessage;
    }
});

$('input:submit').click(function (e) {
    warnMessage = null;
});
```

This is used to display a message when a user tries to close out a browser window or navigate to a new page when they click on a link for instance.  It works good with the exception that this code excludes ALL submit type buttons.

I have 3 submit buttons with ID's MainContent_Button1, MainContent_Button2, MainContent_Button3.  How can I modify the above code so that it excludes these 3 buttons.  In addition, I want these three buttons NOT to set warnMessage to null and I want these 3 buttons to allow for the onbeforeunload event.  I tried to simply call out each button and do a:

```
$("#MainContent_Button1").click(function (e) {
    warnMessage = "You have unsaved changes on this page!";
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        return warnMessage;
    }
});
```

But this did not work even if I put it before the above code...So is there any way with what I posted at the top to exclude it for these 3 buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty easy, i think you were on the right track. You can use the `.not()` function from jQuery. See the following code:

```
$('input,textarea,select').change(function () {
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        if (warnMessage != null) return warnMessage;
    }
});

$('input:submit').not('#MainContent_Button1, #MainContent_Button2, #MainContent_Button3').click(function (e) {
    warnMessage = null;
});
```

Comment: So do I change my original functions or just add this one?

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind-This doesn't seem to make sense what you posted.  I want to trigger the onbeforeunload for those buttons.  Wouldn't not exclude those buttons?  Can you use my existing code and provide a solution please?

Comment: ok, i may have misunderstood your question.  so everything is working correctly on your page?  The only thing you need is to trigger the onbeforeload function when you click each of those 3 buttons you mentioned?  Is this correct?

Comment: Lets say I have 5 buttons, 3 of them (MainContent_Button1 through MainContent_Button3) I want them NOT to set warnMessage to null and I want them to TRIGGER the onbeforeunload event.  The other 2 buttons lets say MainContent_Button4 and MainContent_Button5 I want those two to set warnMessage to null.  I can easily do that part with `$(input:submit').not(CONTROLS FOR 1 THROUGH 3 HERE).change(..)` my issue is the first function the one that I posted in my question.

Comment: `$('input:submit').not('#MainContent_btnSetClearSignOff0, #MainContent_btnSetClearSignOff, #MainContent_btnSetNASignOff0, #MainContent_btnSetNASignOff, #MainContent_btnSetNoSignOff0, #MainContent_btnSetNoSignOff, #MainContent_btnSetYesSignOff0, #MainContent_btnSetYesSignOff, #MainContent_btnSetSelectedClear0, #MainContent_btnSetSelectedClear, #MainContent_btnSetSelectedNA0, #MainContent_btnSetSelectedNA, #MainContent_btnSetSelectedNo0, #MainContent_btnSetSelectedNo, #MainContent_btnSetSelectedYes0, #MainContent_btnSetSelectedYes').click(function (e) {
warnMessage = null;
            });`

Comment: Got it by just filtering those out and then allowing submit and buttons.

Comment: OK cool, yes that is all you can do.  Of course since you have like 20 buttons there, you could have just used a class, say, called: "button_class" and do this:  `$('input:submit').not('.button_class').click(function...`.  It would just make the code look prettier, but I am glad that you go it!